# To pronounce -thful- as /v/?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-clusters

Billy Joel pronounces "truthfulness" like /tʃu:v(ə)nəs/ in *Honesty*. Is it common to pronounce -thful- as /v/?
Any other examples?

> […]
> You can have the love you need to live
> But if [you look for truthfulness](https://youtu.be/SuFScoO4tb0?si=XrK8Xync3EK4UJOQ&t=22)
> You might just as well be blind
> It always seems to be so hard to give

The word is uttered at the 23-second mark.

Comment: Nope. Can't hear that at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires us to listen for something at an unspecified location in a video of a song by _Billy Joel_.

Comment: The singer skips over "th" and heads straight for the "f" which results in  *trufulnes*. The "f" heard is not quite a "v" sound, but it comes quite close.

Comment: [It's common in many dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8th%E2%9F%A9#Dialectal_realizations) to front the dental fricatives  [θ] and [ð] so they become labiodental fricatives [f] and [v]. Not going to listen to the video, though.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I won't use some video links on this site. But I am glad to see that it is common in many dialects. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The OP has cued it so that th YouTube video starts on that very line.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, I heard that too. Reminds me of the Essex (England) and Cockney accents, where e.g. 'Matthew' becomes 'Maffew'.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - yes, I have gathered that, but it is subject to the pleasure of YouTube.